# Json-server не дает авторизоваться / зарегистрироваться

Tags: json, frontend, backend, auth

Возможно есть те, кто использует `json-server` (моковая бекенд-библиотека) и смогут помочь.

Я задеплоил `json-server` на `vercel`. Все запросы проходят, но аутентификация (`json-server-auth`) не работает как надо. Просто пишет: "You must add a "users" collection to your db". Но там уже есть "users". Причем он даже знает, что библиотека есть, потому что до этого просил ее добавить. Целый день потратил на это, но так и не понял, почему просит добавить то, что и так есть.

Так выглядит код сервера:

```
const jsonServer = require("json-server");
const auth = require("json-server-auth");

const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router("server/db.json");
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();

server.db = router.db;

// Add this before server.use(router)
server.use(middlewares);
server.use(auth);

server.use(router);
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("JSON Server is running");
});

// Export the Server API
module.exports = server;
```

Вот ссылка на деплой: https://json-server-vercel-test-eight.vercel.app/ ("users" там есть).
Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?